# What is maximum points limit for Google's heatmap feature?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Hello there's I am use google's Heatmap feature in my project. I do not know whats the maximum points (latitude ,longitude )limit for google's heatmap to visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of points added to the heatmap, but there are practical constraints (the memory of the device displaying them, the time to load them, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

Longitude is in the range -180 and +180 specifying coordinates west and east of the Prime Meridian, respectively. For reference, the Equator has a latitude of 0°, the North pole has a latitude of 90° north (written 90° N or +90°), and the South pole has a latitude of -90°.
The limit is for longitude and latitude not for google heatmap feature for using latitude or longitude. If your latitude/longitude is in valid range , it will work.

Comment: I think you did not get my question. 
https://jsfiddle.net/qpdxpnpb/13/
please look above link I am showing more more than 500 points. I am asking is there any limit for that points.

Comment: It depends on the API you are using, javascript, android or ios. Google generally restricts on requests/loads per day. Here is the link
https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/